# How to print a page in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a module for drupal 7 that generate reports. I want to print one of the reports with out drupal menus and footer. I want the report to be displayed on second page alone with view descriptive data?
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

After hacking in to print module's cod. I found that to generat blank drupal page use the following in the link call back

drupal_send_headers();
  print $myHTML;

Answer (score 0):

In your page callback you can simply print out the information you want and then die, but that will prevent shutdown functions and hook_exit tasks.  The better way would be to use drupal_page_footer()

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_page_footer/7